# Why is my chatroom based on python sockets only allow one client to join?

Tags: python, client-server, python-sockets

When I have a client join the server, all is well. However, when I add another client and they try to send more than one message, the error

> "Reading Error: "

shows up. Also, messages from clients don't show up on each other's screens. See the code below.

SERVER.PY

```
import socket
import select
HEADER_LENGTH = 10
global ipad
hostn = socket.gethostname()
ipad = socket.gethostbyname(hostn)
lol = "0.0.0.0"
IP = (lol)
PORT = 1234
# Create a socket
# socket.AF_INET - address family, IPv4, some otehr possible are AF_INET6, AF_BLUETOOTH, AF_UNIX
# socket.SOCK_STREAM - TCP, conection-based, socket.SOCK_DGRAM - UDP, connectionless, datagrams, socket.SOCK_RAW - raw IP packets
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# SO_ - socket option
# SOL_ - socket option level
# Sets REUSEADDR (as a socket option) to 1 on socket
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
# Bind, so server informs operating system that it's going to use given IP and port
# For a server using 0.0.0.0 means to listen on all available interfaces, useful to connect locally to 127.0.0.1 and remotely to LAN interface IP
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
# This makes server listen to new connections
server_socket.listen()
# List of sockets for select.select()
sockets_list = [server_socket]
# List of connected clients - socket as a key, user header and name as data
clients = {}
print(f'Listening for connections on {IP}:{PORT}...')
# Handles message receiving
def receive_message(client_socket):
    try:
        # Receive our "header" containing message length, it's size is defined and constant
        message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
        # If we received no data, client gracefully closed a connection, for example using socket.close() or socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        if not len(message_header):
            return False
        # Convert header to int value
        message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
        # Return an object of message header and message data
        return {'header': message_header, 'data': client_socket.recv(message_length)}
    except:
        # If we are here, client closed connection violently, for example by pressing ctrl+c on his script
        # or just lost his connection
        # socket.close() also invokes socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR) what sends information about closing the socket (shutdown read/write)
        # and that's also a cause when we receive an empty message
        return False
while True:
    # Calls Unix select() system call or Windows select() WinSock call with three parameters:
    #   - rlist - sockets to be monitored for incoming data
    #   - wlist - sockets for data to be send to (checks if for example buffers are not full and socket is ready to send some data)
    #   - xlist - sockets to be monitored for exceptions (we want to monitor all sockets for errors, so we can use rlist)
    # Returns lists:
    #   - reading - sockets we received some data on (that way we don't have to check sockets manually)
    #   - writing - sockets ready for data to be send thru them
    #   - errors  - sockets with some exceptions
    # This is a blocking call, code execution will "wait" here and "get" notified in case any action should be taken
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], sockets_list)


    # Iterate over notified sockets
    for notified_socket in read_sockets:

        # If notified socket is a server socket - new connection, accept it
        if notified_socket == server_socket:

            # Accept new connection
            # That gives us new socket - client socket, connected to this given client only, it's unique for that client
            # The other returned object is ip/port set
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

            # Client should send his name right away, receive it
            user = receive_message(client_socket)

            # If False - client disconnected before he sent his name
            if user is False:
                continue

            # Add accepted socket to select.select() list
            sockets_list.append(client_socket)

            # Also save username and username header
            clients[client_socket] = user

            print('Accepted new connection from {}:{}, username: {}'.format(*client_address, user['data'].decode('utf-8')))

        # Else existing socket is sending a message
        else:

            # Receive message
            message = receive_message(notified_socket)

            # If False, client disconnected, cleanup
            if message is False:
                print('Closed connection from: {}'.format(clients[notified_socket]['data'].decode('utf-8')))

                # Remove from list for socket.socket()
                sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)

                # Remove from our list of users
                del clients[notified_socket]

                continue

            # Get user by notified socket, so we will know who sent the message
            user = clients[notified_socket]

            print(f'Received message from {user["data"].decode("utf-8")}: {message["data"].decode("utf-8")}')

            # Iterate over connected clients and broadcast message
            for client_socket in clients:

                # But don't sent it to sender
                if client_socket != notified_socket:

                    # Send user and message (both with their headers)
                    # We are reusing here message header sent by sender, and saved username header send by user when he connected
                    client_socket.send(user['header'] + user['data'] + message['header'] + message['data'])

    # It's not really necessary to have this, but will handle some socket exceptions just in case
    for notified_socket in exception_sockets:

        # Remove from list for socket.socket()
        sockets_list.remove(notified_socket)

        # Remove from our list of users
        del clients[notified_socket]
```

I think that the issue is in my server code, but I'll give you guys the client code for extra detail.

CLIENT.PY

```
import socket
import select
import errno
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import sys
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f_obj = Fernet(key)
HEADER_LENGTH = 10

global ipad
hostn = socket.gethostname()
ipad = socket.gethostbyname(hostn)

IP = (ipad)
PORT = 1234
my_username = input("Username: ")

# Create a socket
# socket.AF_INET - address family, IPv4, some otehr possible are AF_INET6, AF_BLUETOOTH, AF_UNIX
# socket.SOCK_STREAM - TCP, conection-based, socket.SOCK_DGRAM - UDP, connectionless, datagrams, socket.SOCK_RAW - raw IP packets
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to a given ip and port
client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))

# Set connection to non-blocking state, so .recv() call won't block, just return some exception we'll handle
client_socket.setblocking(False)

# Prepare username and header and send them
# We need to encode username to bytes, then count number of bytes and prepare header of fixed size, that we encode to bytes as well
username = my_username.encode('utf-8')
username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
client_socket.send(username_header + username)

while True:

    # Wait for user to input a message
    message = input(f'{my_username} > ')
    

    # If message is not empty - send it
    if message:

        # Encode message to bytes, prepare header and convert to bytes, like for username above, then send
        message = message.encode('utf-8')
        encrypted_msg = f_obj.encrypt(message)
        message_header = f"{len(encrypted_msg):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
        client_socket.send(message_header + encrypted_msg)

    try:
        # Now we want to loop over received messages (there might be more than one) and print them
        while True:

            # Receive our "header" containing username length, it's size is defined and constant
            username_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

            # If we received no data, server gracefully closed a connection, for example using socket.close() or socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            if not len(username_header):
                print('Connection closed by the server')
                sys.exit()

            # Convert header to int value
            username_length = int(username_header.decode('utf-8').strip())

            # Receive and decode username
            username = client_socket.recv(username_length).decode('utf-8')

            # Now do the same for message (as we received username, we received whole message, there's no need to check if it has any length)
            message_header = f"{len(encrypted_msg):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('utf-8')
            message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
            encrypted_msg = client_socket.recv(message_header).decode('utf-8')
            message = f_obj.decrypt(encrypted_msg)

            # Print message
            print(f'{username} > {message}')

    except IOError as e:
        # This is normal on non blocking connections - when there are no incoming data error is going to be raised
        # Some operating systems will indicate that using AGAIN, and some using WOULDBLOCK error code
        # We are going to check for both - if one of them - that's expected, means no incoming data, continue as normal
        # If we got different error code - something happened
        if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN and e.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            print('Reading error: {}'.format(str(e)))
            sys.exit()

        # We just did not receive anything
        continue

    except Exception as e:
        # Any other exception - something happened, exit
        print('Reading error: '.format(str(e)))
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: If you have an error you should paste it into your post. Also your title is in all caps, you should fix that since it's considered to be rude shouting.

Comment: There are many examples of chat clients in Python available online; studying those to understand how they work may help you figure out what's wrong with your code. See e.g, [1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/simple-chat-room-using-python/), [2](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/make-a-chat-room-application-in-python), etc.

Comment: My only error shows up on the client side and it just reads "Reading Error:  " shows up on both client scripts.